# Pass class instance by reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm learning C++ while I developing a planetarium software. I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.

I having troubles with passing two classes instances by reference.

This is how I create the two class instances and pass them to the method:

```
MyTime* newRightAscension = new MyTime(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DegreesCoordinate* newDeclination = new DegreesCoordinate(0, 0, 0, NotSet);

precession->RigorousMethod(epoch1, rightAscension, declination, epoch2, newRightAscension, newDeclination);
```

This is `precession->RigorousMethod` method declaration:

```
void Precession::RigorousMethod(
    DateTime * epoch1,
    MyTime * rightAscension,
    DegreesCoordinate * declination,
    DateTime * epoch2,
    MyTime* newRightAscension,
    DegreesCoordinate* newDeclination)
```

And this how I update `newRightAscension` and `newDeclination` value inside that method:

```
newDeclination = new DegreesCoordinate(decResult->getDegrees(), decResult->getMinutes(), decResult->getSeconds(), decResult->getDirection());
newRightAscension = new MyTime(raResult->getHour(), raResult->getMinute(), raResult->getSeconds(), raResult->getTimeZone(), raResult->getDayLightSavings());
```

Creating a new instance, but when I check those values after method execution they don't have those values.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you showed is passing a pointer, not an "instance by reference" and your intended use seems to require passing a pointer by reference: In the signature of `RigorousMethod`  ,that would be `DegreesCoordinate*& newDeclination`.  But then what you described looks like a memory leak, so you probably should change more than that.

Comment: You are creating a new class instances on newDeclination and newRightAscension  inside the method, overriding the value of the pointer passed to the function (and causing a memory leak). If you want to change the values of the class members of the instance created outside the function, just call the set functions. If you want to allocate the new instance inside the function, you need to pass ** or *& - dont need to allocate outside the function.

Comment: Do you really want to change `newDeclination` by creating a new object for it to point to?  That would be done by passing by `*&` as I described in my first comment.  But passing by `&` and changing the contents of the object (rather than creating a new object) may make more sense.

Comment: You're treating C++ like C#. While C# has value types and reference types, C++ has only value semantics for its types--`ComplicatedType b{}; ComplicatedType a = b` will make two objects, one (`b`) default constructed, one copied from `b`: alterations to `a` won't alter `b`. You're correct that the closest thing to C# reference types in C++ is pointers, but have neglected that C++ doesn't manage your memory for you. You should look into smart pointers--`shared_ptr` probably offers the closest thing to what you're used to when it comes to memory management, with a few caveats...

Comment: What you've done here is make a copy of the pointer pointing to your resource, and then alter the copy of the pointer, not the original pointer, and not the resource pointed by the original pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach (using pointers passed by reference):

```
MyTime* newRightAscension = 0;  // Don't create an object yet
DegreesCoordinate* newDeclination = 0;

precession->RigorousMethod(epoch1, rightAscension, declination, epoch2, newRightAscension, newDeclination);
```

...

```
void Precession::RigorousMethod(
    DateTime * epoch1,
    MyTime * rightAscension,
    DegreesCoordinate * declination,
    DateTime * epoch2,
    MyTime*& newRightAscension,
    DegreesCoordinate*& newDeclination)
```

That makes sense when it is that function's responsibility to create those two objects.  So you don't want to initialize the pointers to dummy objects.  The pointers don't need to be initialized at all when declared, but initializing to 0 will make the code safer.

Answer (score 0):

Outside `RigorousMethod` you allocate memory for a `MyTime` and `DegreesCoordinate` objects. When you call the method, you pass pointers to these memory addresses, you do not pass references. Inside your method you simply reset the memory addresses of your local pointer variables (which originally pointed to the memory addresses of the objects you created outside of the method) by setting them to addresses of newly allocated objects. This of course has no effect on the original instances. Instead, the only effect is that you have a memory leak as no pointer outside of `RigorousMethod` has access to the newly created objects. If you want to see a quick effect, alter the arguments from `Type*` to `Type&`, changing pointers to references, and replace `pointer_to_object = new Constructor{ /*something*/ }`. with `reference_to_object = Constructor{ /*something*/ }`, e.g. change `MyTime*` -> `MyTime&` and `newRightAscension = new MyTime{ /*something*/ }` to `newRightAscension = MyTime{ /*something*/ }`. Then you pass your arguments as `*pointer_to_object`, instead of just passing `pointer_to_object`.